# Maven add SVN Revision to manifest

Tags: svn, maven

I tried to add my current SVN Revision Number to the war's manifest file using buildnumber-maven-plugin.

In pom.xml I added:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <revisionOnScmFailure>0.0.1</revisionOnScmFailure>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>x ${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but after deploying the file, the manifest file looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: my.name
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_33
Implementation-Title: Java EE 6 webapp project
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.company.my
Implementation-Build: x ${buildNumber}
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
```

so the `${buildNumber}` is not evaluated for whatever reason. (Also the `revisionOnScmFaulure` Options doesn't seem to work. ( I added the "x" for debug reasons. )

When I run the project as maven build, I get the following error:

```
"Unknown lifecycle phase "create". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy."
```

However, changing the goal to anything other than create doesn't fix the problem and causes validator errors.

Comment: Have you tried to update the maven-war-plugin to the current version (2.3) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise tried, no effect. Same issue.

Comment: 'build' and 'create' are not Maven lifecycle phases.  What if you try `mvn package` instead?

Comment: I think that the property is not evaluated because war is packaged on `package` phase, and `validate` comes after it. Try to change `validate` into `package` (or `prepare-package`).

Comment: think i found the problem: When calling `svn info` from cmd, i received an error that the project is subversion 1.6, and needs to be updated. Updating it and the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` is working as expected. However this was just a test, and updating the project to 1.7 will cause a lot of tools (and other devs) to stop working :) So not an option at the moment. So i'll test it with an 1.6 command line client again.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it works for, say, [rexsl project](http://www.rexsl.com) (see their [pom.xml](http://trac.fazend.com/rexsl/browser/rexsl/tags/rexsl-0.4.4/rexsl/pom.xml)):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <buildNumberPropertyName>buildNumber</buildNumberPropertyName>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <getRevisionOnlyOnce>true</getRevisionOnlyOnce>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <ReXSL-Version>${project.version}</ReXSL-Version>
                            <ReXSL-Build>${buildNumber}</ReXSL-Build>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```